# How can I get the requested entry from a plugin?

Tags: plugin-development, entrymodel, routing, entry

If I’m accessing an entry’s URL (the 4th check in [Routing](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/routing)), how can I get the entry that the URL matched from a plugin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the request’s matched element via:

```php
$element = craft()->urlManager->getMatchedElement();
```

There are two things to remember though:

1. There may not be a matched element
2. The matched element might not be an *entry*. (It could also be a category, and if you have any plugins installed that add their own element types that can have their own URLs, it could be one of those.)

To defend against those possibilities, just use the following conditional:

```php
if ($element && $element->getElementType() == ElementType::Entry)
{
    // There was a matched element, and it's an entry!
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Will this work in elementapi when setting up end points?

Comment: @joomkit No, in that case the matched element(s) are passed directly to your tranformer function, so there's no need to have a separate way to access them. If you're having trouble trying to get something set up please post as a new question :)