# Get Handle/Name of Entry's Section

Tags: templating, entry, sections

For theming, I need to get the Section Handle for the current Entry. When using dump(entry), I see **sectionId** is available. This works fine:

```
{{ entry.sectionId }}
```

But I'm not seeing a way to get the **sectionHandle**. Does anyone know a quick way to get it?

Comment: We already had this question, it's even answered by Brandon of P&T: ["Get the current page Handle"](http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/q/1682/125).

Comment: No idea how I didn't find that when searching. I was looking for "Entry" handles, and that question specifies it as "Page". It does answer my question though!
Does the trick:

{% set section = entry.getSection() %}
{% set handle = section.handle %}

Comment: Yep "Page" is not the best term to ask this question. Glad you found what you need, Zack!

Comment: I know a way to fix that — change the title ;)