# Commerce: How can I check if I am on a specific product page?

Tags: templating, plugin-craftcommerce

I know there are ways to [check current section](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/1682/get-the-current-section-handle). I would like to check if I am on a specific product (commerce) page.

I am able to do this in a plugin by checking line item(s) and the product type. Is there a similar way to do the same at the twig level?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the same approach as the link provided in your question. Only, instead of an entry, you're working with a *product*.

For example:

**template.twig**

```
{# Get the current section - set fallback(s) for entries or products or ?? #}
{% set section = entry.getSection() | default(entry.getSection() ?? product.getType() ?? null) %}
{% if section %}
    {% set handle = section.handle %}
    {{ handle }} {# myProductType #}
{% endif %}
```

Here we are checking if we're on an entry. If not, we've set a fallback to check if we're on a product page. If nothing, the we return null.

Once we've got our section, we can check the handle. Then it's a matter of checking for the type you are looking for.

```
...
{% if handle == 'myHandle' %}
    <p>We've got a winner!</p>
{% endif %}
```