# Get the localized handle and slug for "current" section for constructing breadcrumbs

Tags: templating, localization, sections, multi-site

I'm trying to contruct breadcrumbs for entries under a specific section. This feels like such a "how-hard-could-it-possibly-be" type of question, but I've been at this for a lot more time than I ever expected, so finally asking a question here.
So far, this the relevant parts of what I have:

```
{% macro breadcrumbs(type, entryId) %} 
    {% if type == 'article' %}
        {% set articleEntry = craft.entries.id(entryId).one() %}
        
        {% set section = craft.app.sections.getSectionByHandle('articles') %}
        {% set sectionUrl = siteUrl ~ section.handle|kebab %}

        {{ dd(sectionUrl, section.name) }}
    {% endif %}
{% endmacro %}
```

This (so far) simple macro is called from the article template.
The `dd` here outputs the following:

```
^ "//localhost:3000/sv/articles"
^ "Articles"
```

`articles` should really be `artiklar` in both the contructed URL as well as the name.

I have looked at [this question](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/1682/get-the-current-section-handle) which is 7 years old, but it only fetches the sections "main" name, handle and uri.

`articles` is a channel, if that matters.

I realize I'm probably going about this issue in totally the wrong way. Feel free to give me pointers on where I'm going wrong.

Edit: @moritzlost made the issue quite apparent: The page that handles the listing/overview of all articles, isn't actually a part of the `articles` channel. This is of course obvious. I'll leave the question stand in case others end up in the same brain-warp.

What my code ended up looking like:

```
{% macro breadcrumbs(type, entryId) %} 
    {% if type == 'article' %}
        {% set articleEntry = craft.entries.id(entryId).one() %}
        
        {% set section = craft.entries().section('articlesListing').one() %}
        {% set sectionUrl = section.getUrl() %}
        {% set sectionName = section.seo.metaGlobalVars.seoTitle %} {# Gets the SEO title instead of the default section name. #}

        {{ dd(sectionUrl, sectionName) }}
    {% endif %}
{% endmacro %}
```

Which yields this:

```
^ "//localhost:3000/sv/artiklar"
^ "Artiklar om djurhållning"
```

Comment: What link(s) are you trying to output? What kind of content (section, entry type) are you serving for that link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A section's `handle` is the machine-readable identifier for a section, it's not localizable and has nothing to do with URLs of entries in that section. Instead of accessing the section in your template, you need *the entries in that section* to get their localized URLs.

Since you'te talking about breadcrumbs, I'll assume you want a list of links like this:

```
/articles/
/articles/article-about-something/
```

In your example, the current entry would have the URL `/articles/article-about-something/` and you're trying to get the link to `articles`. Now the solution depends on what section the `articles` belongs to. Since your `articles` section is a channel (so no hierarchies), I assume your `/articles/` pages is another section, probably a single? In this case, you'll want to use an entry query to get that single entry and access its URL, which will be localized automatically:

```twig
{% set articlesListing = craft.entries().section('articlesListing').one() %}
{% if articles_index %}
    {% set articles_url = articlesListing.getUrl() %}
{% endif %}
```

---

If the `/articles/` page is a static route or just matched based on the template name, there's no built-in way to localize it. You'll have to hard-code your local URLs and make sure your routes/template names match all localized slugs.

Comment: Right you are. /articles/ is of course not part of the section "Articles" at all, but rather it's a single called "articlesListing". So yea, `craft.entries().section('articlesListing').one()` does indeed give me the right thing. I will fix my question to reflect this serious oversight. Thanks.